# why the number of vector of INT0 is 1 not 2 as datasheet?

Tags: embedded, interrupt, avr, avr-gcc

I am using an ATmega32 to do interrupt 
when i trying to do driver of external interrupt 0 , faced me a problem

Interrupt Vectors Table in ATmega32

[image]

Interrupt Vectors code in ISR(vector)

[image]

In iom32.h code , we see that ((INT0_vect   " _VECTOR(1) ")) it's number 1 but in data sheet we see that the number is 2 , why ?

Comment: Zero-based versus one-based numbering? `_VECTOR(1)` is probably referring to the *second* element in the ISR, being a zero-base numbered array.

Comment: _VECROR(1) , it's code is #define _VECTOR(N) __vector_ ## N

Comment: what does the disassembly or hexdump of the resulting binary show?  Is the table not being built correctly?

Comment: please post the results of the build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datasheet starts numbering with the reset vector. But there is no need for an explicit define (like RESET_vect) for the reset vector, since it will not be used in conjunction with ISR(). So in the header/AVRGCC implementation it is omitted.

If you compile this

```
ISR(INT0_vect) {  }
```

and look at the interrupt vector table

```
00000000 <__vectors>:
0:  0c 94 46 00     jmp 0x8c    ; 0x8c <__ctors_end>
4:  0c 94 5f 00     jmp 0xbe    ; 0xbe <__vector_1>
```

you can see that __vector_1 is placed at byte address 4, which corresponds to the word address 2 from the data sheet.

Comment: Of course the reset vector is used as an ISR target, or the program wouldn't start. How you can place code in the reset ISR if it's not part of the vector table?

Comment: @Lundin: What I wanted to point out is, that there is no need for an explicit define (like RESET_vect) for the reset vector. I probably worded that first sentence not so well, English is not my native language.

Comment: Why not? That's how it's commonly done on all manner of different MCU tool chains.

Comment: @Lundin: Are we talking about the same thing? Do you refer to a programmatic way to jump to the reset vector?

Comment: No, I'm referring to a programmatic way to implement the reset ISR contents, meaning that the linker must know of it somehow.

Comment: @Lundin: For AVR, I do not know of a way to execute specific code before the reset is actually executed when a reset was triggered. Do you?

Comment: The reset ISR is executed _after_ a reset (be it POR, watchdog reset or whatever). It's the point of entry of any MCU program.

Comment: @Lundin: Let me ask different: It what scenario would you need the fictional "RESET_vect" definition that is not part of the header file and thus caused the confusion for OP regarding the vector numbering?

Comment: Suppose I have a bootloader which is programming the interrupt vector table. The programmer is however probably not as interested in the address of the reset ISR, as in the ability to write that ISR themselves. In which case it needs to link, in which case the linker must be made aware it is an ISR and therefore not called by code.